# Publish asmx web service to FTP server given parser error

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asmx

I created web service **Webservice.asmx** in web application named **Publish_test** using VS2013. Every thing is working find,but when i publish it to host i got this error :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'Publish_test.MyWebService.WebService'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/WebService.asmx.cs" Class="Publish_test.MyWebService.WebService" %>

Source File: /test/test/MyWebService/WebService.asmx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5485; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5483
```

My web Service Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Publish_test.MyWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://src-services.com/test/test/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the .net framework version of your project and iis?

Comment: My .net framework 4.5,I don't thins the problem from name of web service because the name WebService1 and I change to WebService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define the directory that content the web service in ftp host as **application pool**

Answer (score 0):

```
   change
  CodeBehind="~/WebService.asmx.cs" to CodeFile="~/WebService.asmx.cs"
```

Comment: **CodeFile** attribute not support by **WebService**  directive.